# Python code in AWS lambda - execution breaks after 1st occurrence of failed case

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a dictionary with keys as key1, key2, key3 and values as s3 paths which hold some files, I am looping dict to check if file exists in the path.

1. In the sequence if files exists in all paths - scripts works fine
2. In the sequence if last file does not exists - scripts works fine
3. In the sequence if any one of the files does not exists (in between) in path - script jumps to exception block and exits, where I want the execution to be continued after a failure case (file not exists)

I tried to use break, continue statements in between to control execution as per my requirement, but still not achieving what I wanted.

```
import boto3
import botocore, os, datetime, csv
from io import StringIO
import time, json
from datetime import timedelta


def lambda_handler(event, context):

    client = boto3.resource('s3')
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    TS = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y%m%d')

    st = datetime.datetime.now()+ timedelta(hours = 5.5)
    st = st.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

    Buck = 'mybuck'
    Feed = {"key1": "test/Disk_space1_"+TS+"_0001"+".PNG",
            "key2": "EC2/EC2_InstanceID_Input_File.csv", 
            "key3": "EC2/test2/AWSError.PNG"}

    try:
        for key, value in Feed.items():
            print(value)
            obj = client.Bucket(Buck).Object(value).load()

            #print(obj)
            if obj is None: 
                print(obj)
                contents = st +' '+ key+ ' '+'File-exists!'
                target_bucket = 'mybuck'
                target_file = 'EC2/hello.csv'

                open('/tmp/test.txt', 'a+').write(contents)
                open('/tmp/test.txt', 'a+').write('\r\n')
                s3.upload_file('/tmp/test.txt', Buck, target_file)

    except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as error:
        contents1 = st +' '+ key+ ' '+'File-doesnot-exists!'
        print('File does not exists in path:',value+' '+'ErrMsg:',error)
        open('/tmp/test.txt', 'a+').write(contents1)
        open('/tmp/test.txt', 'a+').write('\r\n')
        s3.upload_file('/tmp/test.txt', Buck, target_file)
```

Comment: Why is my question down voted, I have taken efforts to resolve issue on my own and I have shown what I have tried and what worked for me and not. I have followed  guidelines to the best of my understanding, please don't demotivate us by down voting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the code which is throwing the exception in a closer try/catch.  This would most likely mean wrapping the `client.Bucket(...)` line.  If you caught the exception within the loop you could use `continue` to skip that iteration.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried to bring in try except block under for loop which helped me, will give my updated code in answer.

Comment: You should mark this question as accepted rather than creating your own answer with @Daniel's solution!

Comment: I didn't created answer with Daniel's solution.. please look closer, my answer is different from his solution.

Comment: Your answer is to move the try/except into the for loop, which is exactly what my answer suggested you do.

Answer (score 0):

My for loop was under try..except block, I tried to bring try..except block under for loop which resolved the issue.

```
import boto3
import botocore, os, datetime, csv
from io import StringIO
import time, json
from datetime import timedelta


def lambda_handler(event, context):

    client = boto3.resource('s3')
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    TS = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y%m%d')

    st = datetime.datetime.now()+ timedelta(hours = 5.5)
    st = st.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

    Buck = 'mybuck'
    Feed = {"key1": "test/Disk_space1_"+TS+"_0001"+".PNG",
            "key2": "EC2/EC2_InstanceID_Input_File.csv", 
            "key3": "EC2/test2/AWSError.PNG"}


    for key, value in Feed.items():
        print(value)
        try:
            obj = client.Bucket(Buck).Object(value).load()

            #print(obj)
            if obj is None: 
                print(obj)
                contents = st +' '+ key+ ' '+'File-exists!'
                target_bucket = 'mybuck'
                target_file = 'EC2/hello.csv'

                open('/tmp/test.txt', 'a+').write(contents)
                open('/tmp/test.txt', 'a+').write('\r\n')
                s3.upload_file('/tmp/test.txt', Buck, target_file)

        except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as error:
            contents1 = st +' '+ key+ ' '+'File-doesnot-exists!'
            print('File does not exists in path:',value+' '+'ErrMsg:',error)
            open('/tmp/test.txt', 'a+').write(contents1)
            open('/tmp/test.txt', 'a+').write('\r\n')
            s3.upload_file('/tmp/test.txt', Buck, target_file)
```